# Magento2 New theme without parent theme

Tags: magento2

is there a possibility to create new theme without parent theme?
Currently if you add parent as blank theme it comes with knockout and unused Js which is not required and affects performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parent theme is necessary in Magento, if you don't want any parent theme, you can use blank theme as your parent theme:

```
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
```

And this wont be an issue, your theme will work properly if you do this.

See [dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) for details